# Can't get list of object from appsettings

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration

I have app settings that look like this:

```
"Tenants": [
  {
    "Id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000",
    "ConnectionString": "dbstring"
  },
  {
    "Id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000001",
    "ConnectionString": "dbstring"
  }
]
```

and an object that looks like this:

```
public class TenantSecrets
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class Tenants : List<TenantSecrets> { }
```

When I  try to either configure them or bind them like so:

```
services.Configure<Tenants>(Configuration.GetSection("Tenants"));

var tenants = new Tenants();
Configuration.Bind("Tenants", tenants);
```

The list is always empty, does anyone know why or how I can debug it? I can see the list in the appsettings configuration reader when I debug it, but the object never seems to map.

Comment: that still produces an empty list

Answer (score 1):

ok people, i figured it out, turns out that the empty guid i was using for the Id was one 0 short of a guid, and i have now learnt that config to poco mapping fails silently, so for anyone else having issues, please check that your data fits the data types

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
Good, you spotted this mistake, it happens it works perfectly. I don't want to write a useless answer so here is the version using the [Options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Configure the `Tenants` class in the `Startup.cs` file (method **ConfigureServices**)

```
services.Configure<Tenants>(Configuration.GetSection("Tenants"));
```

Then, inject the `IOptions<Tenants>` service in a controller constructor.

```
private readonly Tenants _tenants;

public HomeController(IOptions<Tenants> tenantOptions)
{
    _tenants = tenantOptions.Value;
}
```